# How to implement name-less methods in typescript interfaces?

Tags: typescript

Working on a graph visualization task, I found the following interface in the d3.js typings (upstream link [here](https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-v4-definitelytyped/blob/master/src/d3-force/index.d.ts)):

```
export interface Force<NodeDatum extends SimulationNodeDatum, LinkDatum extends SimulationLinkDatum<NodeDatum> | undefined> {
    (alpha: number): void; // <- ???
    initialize?(nodes: NodeDatum[]): void;
}
```

This `(alpha: number): void;` seems to me a little bit uncommon. My intuition from different OOP languages says as if it would be some like a C++ [functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses). But I couldn't find the correct syntax to implement it.

What is it?

How can I implement this interface?

How can I call this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types) :

> Function Types
>   Interfaces are capable of describing the wide range of shapes that
>   JavaScript objects can take. In addition to describing an object with
>   properties, interfaces are also capable of describing function types.
>
> To describe a function type with an interface, we give the interface a
>   call signature. This is like a function declaration with only the
>   parameter list and return type given. Each parameter in the parameter
>   list requires both name and type.
>
> ```
> interface SearchFunc {
>     (source: string, subString: string): boolean; 
> }
> ```
>
> Once defined, we can use this function type interface like we would other interfaces.
>   Here, we show how you can create a variable of a function type and
>   assign it a function value of the same type.
>
> ```
> let mySearch: SearchFunc;
> mySearch = function(source: string, subString: string) {
>     let result = source.search(subString);
>     return result > -1;
> }
> ```

So you can implement it with

```
let test: Force = function(alpha: number) {
   //do stuff
}
//optional part
test.initialize = function(nodes: NodeDatum[]) {
   //do other stuff
}
```